# Why won't my content pane show up on my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is my graphics class, but when I create and add a JPanel as a content pane to it nothing shows up. I have done many tests to see if my content pane is visible but it still will not show.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GraphicsMain extends JFrame{
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 7610350056926018727L;
    static GraphicsMain frame = new GraphicsMain();
    static final int WIDTH = 1024, HEIGHT = 768;
    static Listener listener = new Listener();

    public static void init() {
        createGUI();
    }

    public static void createGUI() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Game of Life");
        frame.setContentPane(frame.createMainPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        totalGUI.setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        totalGUI.setBackground(Color.red);
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        JPanel buttonPanel = createButtonPanel();

        totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);
        totalGUI.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Is returning!");
        return totalGUI;
    }

    public JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        buttonPanel.setLocation(0, 0);

        Font buttonFont = new Font("Button Font", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        JButton goButton = createButton("Go", WIDTH/16, HEIGHT/12, 10, 10, listener, buttonFont, Color.black);
        buttonPanel.add(goButton);
        JButton clearButton = createButton("Clear", WIDTH/16, HEIGHT/12, 10 + HEIGHT/12, 10, listener, buttonFont, Color.black);
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton);
        JButton exitButton = createButton("Exit", WIDTH/16, HEIGHT/12, 10 + 2*HEIGHT/12, 10, listener, buttonFont, Color.black);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
        return buttonPanel;
    }

    public JButton createButton(String text, int width, int height, int x, int y, ActionListener listener, Font font, Color color) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setSize(width, height);
        button.setLocation(x, y);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        button.setFont(font);
        button.setForeground(Color.red);
        return button;
    }

}
```

this class is called by

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class GameOfLifeMain {
    static boolean running = true;
    static int UPS = 60;
    static GameOfLifeMain main = new GameOfLifeMain();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main.init();
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                double ns = 1000000000.0 / UPS;
                double delta = 0;

                long secondTimer = System.nanoTime();
                while(running) {
                    long now = System.nanoTime();
                    delta += (now - startTime) / ns;
                    startTime = now;
                    while(delta >= 1) {
                    main.update();
                        delta--;
                    }
                    main.render();

                    if(System.nanoTime() - secondTimer > 1000000000) {
                        secondTimer += 1000000000;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        GraphicsMain.init();
    }

    public void update() {
    }

    public void render() {
        //GraphicsMain.render();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your main problem is that with your rendering loop executed on the EDT (the Swing thread), nothing else can happen with the GUI. Use a regular Thread or SwingWorker. Also, make sure to read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: @Radiodef: that should have been an answer. To the OP, I've added the [tag:java] tag to your question to allow more Java experts to see it and evaluate it. In the future you will want to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are (at least) two fold:

- As @Radiodef astutely notes, you're calling a long-running loop on the Swing event thread. Since this thread is completely responsible for the rendering of your GUI and the interacting with the user, your GUI becomes completely frozen.
- You are using null layouts which make you completely responsible for the positioning and size of all components added to the null-layout using component.

I suggest:

- As @Radiodef suggests, do your long-running loop in a background thread such as a SwingWorker. This will allow easier interaction between your GUI and the background process. His link is a good one: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).
- Use nested JPanels, each one using its own layout to achieve the layout desired, one that will run well on any platform and on any video card setting.
- Better to override your drawing JPanels `getPreferredSize(...)` method to have it sized correctly.
- Setting a JPanel to opaque via `setOpaque(true)` will not help since JPanels are already opaque by default.

---

**Edit**
I stand corrected on the last point per Jan Bodnar:

> "However, the default value for this property on most standard JComponent subclasses (such as JButton and JTree) is look-and-feel dependent." For example, the JPanel of the GTK look and feel is not opaque by default.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: The last comment is not correct. The reference says: "However, the default value for this property on most standard JComponent subclasses (such as JButton and JTree) is look-and-feel dependent."

For example, the JPanel of the GTK look and feel is not opaque by defautl.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setOpaque(true)` on your Panel, then the background will be painted. I also noticed that you mixed up WIDTH and HEIGHT when defining the size of your panel (this might be an error).

Comment: JPanels are already opaque by default, and so calling `setOpaque(true)` is unnecessary and will not help.

Comment: On Mac OS (Java 6) it is not always opaque by default